# Javascript - Change Google Chart onClick

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, charts, google-visualization

I have a dropdown with two values the first loads the JS function `loadUK()` onclick and the second loads the function `loadUS()` onclick.

Beneath are the functions:

```
var lstLength = {};
var chartData = [["Crime Types", "Number"]];
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  $('#UKChart').on('click', loadUK);
  $('#USChart').on('click', loadUS);
    });

function loadUK() {

  var counter = 0;
  $.getJSON("result.json", function(json) {
    var input = json;
    for (var i in input) {
      counter = 0;
      for (var x in input[i]) {
        if (51.5>= parseFloat(input[i][x][1])) {
          counter++;
        }
      }
      dictL[i] = counter;
    }
  });

  for (var key in dictL) {
    if (dictL.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      chartData.push([key, dictL[key]]);
    }
  }

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
  var options = {
    title: 'UK Pie Chart',
    is3D: false,
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

function loadUS() {

  var counter = 0;
  $.getJSON("result.json", function(json) {
    var input = json;
    for (var i in input) {
      counter = 0;
      for (var x in input[i]) {
        if (52.5>= parseFloat(input[i][x][1])) {
          counter++;
        }
      }
      dictL[i] = counter;
    }
  });

  for (var key in dictL) {
    if (dictL.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      chartData.push([key, dictL[key]]);
    }
  }

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
  var options = {
    title: 'US Pie Chart',
    is3D: false,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="dropdown-menu"">
           <a class="dropdown-item" id="UKChart" value="UK" onClick="loadUK()">UK</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" id="USChart" value="US" onClick="loadUS()">US</a>
</div>
```

This somewhat works, but I have to click the button twice to get the new chart to load. I wish to click the button once and the chart to load with the new data. It's not a problem with the HTML, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google charts only needs to be loaded once per page
not every time you need to draw a chart
load google first, then setup your buttons

the load statement can even be used instead of --> `$(document).ready`
it will wait for the page to load before returning the callback

see following snippet, recommend similar setup...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  $('#load-uk').on('click', loadUK);
  $('#load-us').on('click', loadUS);
  loadUS();
});

function loadUK() {
  var chartData = [
    ['UK', 'Number'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
  ];

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
  var options = {
    title: 'UK Pie Chart',
    is3D: true,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

function loadUS() {
  var chartData = [
    ['US', 'Number'],
    ['Work',     13],
    ['Eat',      12],
    ['Commute',  4],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    6]
  ];

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
  var options = {
    title: 'US Pie Chart',
    is3D: true,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" id="load-us">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-image"></span><span>&nbsp;Load US</span>
</button>
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" id="load-uk">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-image"></span><span>&nbsp;Load UK</span>
</button>
<div id="piechart_3d"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

to ensure data is loaded before drawing the chart,
move everything inside --> `$.getJSON`

```
function loadUK() {
  var dictL = {};
  var chartData = [["Crime Types", "Number"]];
  var counter = 0;
  $.getJSON("result.json", function(json) {
    var input = json;
    for (var i in input) {
      counter = 0;
      for (var x in input[i]) {
        if (51.5>= parseFloat(input[i][x][1])) {
          counter++;
        }
      }
      dictL[i] = counter;
    }

    for (var key in dictL) {
      if (dictL.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        chartData.push([key, dictL[key]]);
      }
    }

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
    var options = {
      title: 'UK Pie Chart',
      is3D: false,
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Will try it now!

Comment: If I wish to include more functions that have other sets of data for the chart, how would I include this in the global part? thanks

Comment: I think because my functions are asynchronous, the chart data does not change, I have edited the code to show how I am actually getting the data for the chart. I thought inserting static arrays would be easier to show as an example but the issue is with the for loop

Comment: Sorry to complicate things! The for loops do not update the chart data as they are asynchronous, I am unsure how to go about this.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate your functions; load and drawChart. Debug your parameters and container selector text(html).You triggered chart event out DOM elements and give your container to that. I guess delegate type event trigger and seperate function could solve your problem.

see; http://api.jquery.com/delegate/